# Como trazer todos os registros de um determinado filho no mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Comando: `db.collection.find({"people.name"})`

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("11111111111111111111111111"), 
 "people" : {
    "name" : "Jose"
  }
}

{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("222222222222222222222222222"), 
 "people" : {
    "name" : "Willian"
  }
}

{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("333333333333333333333333333"), 
 "people" : {
    "name" : "Ana"
  }
}
```

Saída:

```
{
  "name" : "Jose" 
}
{
  "name" : "Willian" 
}
{
  "name" : "Ana" 
}
```

Comment: Pode traduzir para Português do Brasil, afinal aqui é para os Brasileiros postarem suas duvidas

Comment: Como trazer todos os registros de um determinado filho no mongodb?

Comment: Se pode editar a sua pergunta e colocar tudo em português, tudo bem?

Comment: ok vou reformular a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Após diversas tentativas consegui resolver sozinho, você pode construir a query usando o operador $exists.

db.collections.find({ 
    "people": { $exists: true }}, {_id:0, "people.name": 1 
})